# Unable to create a sample VPC using boto. socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, sockets, ansible, boto, amazon-vpc

I am a beginner and am trying to create a VPC using boto.

```
 [root@localhost orchestration]# cat create-vpc.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto.vpc
import pdb


from boto.vpc import VPCConnection

#c = VPCConnection()

c=boto.vpc.connect_to_region('us-east-1')

vpc = c.create_vpc('10.0.12.0/16')
subnet = c.create_subnet(vpc.id, '10.0.12.1/24')
```

This is my sample script to create a VPC. 
However i am getting an error "gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known"

Here is the complete traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create-vpc.py", line 13, in <module>
    vpc = c.create_vpc('10.0.12.0/16')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/vpc/__init__.py", line 135, in create_vpc
    return self.get_object('CreateVpc', params, VPC)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1192, in get_object
    response = self.make_request(action, params, path, verb)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1116, in make_request
    return self._mexe(http_request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 913, in _mexe
    self.is_secure)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 705, in get_http_connection
    return self.new_http_connection(host, port, is_secure)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 747, in new_http_connection
    connection = self.proxy_ssl(host, is_secure and 443 or 80)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 792, in proxy_ssl
    int(self.proxy_port)), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 559, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I have also configured the ~/.boto file with the access and the secret keys.
FYI,

```
[root@localhost orchestration]# cat ~/.boto
[Credentials]

aws_access_key_id=<my-access-key>
aws_secret_access_key=<my-secret-key>
```

I have also gone through some other similar questions that suggests to add yun.local entry in the /etc/hosts file.

Here are my /etc/hosts file and /etc/resolv.conf files.

```
[root@localhost orchestration]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.240.1 yun.local

[root@localhost orchestration]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search comviva.com
nameserver 172.19.1.10
nameserver 172.19.1.11
nameserver 172.16.1.20
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver 172.16.1.22
```

Also o/p of telnet

```
[root@localhost orchestration]# telnet yun.local 80
Trying 192.168.240.1...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.240.1: Connection refused
```

FYI,

```
[root@localhost orchestration]# nslookup ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Server:         172.19.1.11
Address:        172.19.1.11#53

Name:   ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 54.239.26.182

[root@localhost orchestration]#
[root@localhost orchestration]#
[root@localhost orchestration]# dig ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-18.el7 <<>> ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24619
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.   IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 0  IN      CNAME   ec2.amazonaws.com.
ec2.amazonaws.com.      48      IN      A       54.239.20.1

;; Query time: 153 msec
;; SERVER: 172.19.1.10#53(172.19.1.10)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 17 23:32:12 EST 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 90
```

I also tried to create this VPC using Ansible and as expected got the same error there as well.
How do i overcome this gaierror ? Any answers shall be heartily appreciated.

Comment: Did you define a region to connect to?

Comment: Yes i have defined the region in the python script itself 
`#!/usr/bin/python
import boto.ec2
ec2=boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
print ec2
ec2.run_instances('ami-0129cc68', key_name='/root/IOX_Key.pem', instance_type='t2.micro', security_groups='sg-08d0ba6d')`

Answer (score 0):

To create your VPCConnection (or really any service connection object) in boto, you should use this incantation:

```
import boto.vpc
c = boto.vpc.connect_to_region('us-east-1')  # or whatever
```

In this way, you are guaranteed to have a properly initialized VPCConnection object pointing to the right endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i still get the same error.
`File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 556, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`
[root@localhost orchestration]# cat create-vpc.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto.vpc
import pdb


from boto.vpc import VPCConnection

#c = VPCConnection()

c=boto.vpc.connect_to_region('us-east-1')

vpc = c.create_vpc('10.0.12.0/16')
subnet = c.create_subnet(vpc.id, '10.0.12.1/24')

Comment: Hey Garnet! I am still getting the same error. This has been a blocker for my further AWS orchestration activities. Can you suggest something ?

Comment: The error you are getting is basically a DNS error.  It is unable to find the host associated with the service endpoint.  So, either it is using the wrong host name or your DNS is not working correctly.  Could you possibly update your original question with your current code? Its hard to read it in the comment.

Comment: Your code appears to be correct (although you can remove the "from boto.vpc import VPCConnection" line, it's not doing anything).  Can you add a "print(c.host)" after you have created the connection?  What is the value of host?  It should be "ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com".  Is it?  If so, what happens if you try to lookup that host, e.g. "nslookup ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" or "dig ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"?

Comment: Yes the value of c.host is ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
I have edited the question with the o/p of nslookup and dig!
Kindly suggest!!

Comment: Hey garnet! Can you comment on this? My system is able to resolve the DNS names to IPs. But still why do i get this error?

Comment: Are you going through a proxy server?